# Rcpp function with side effect and copying

Tags: r, rcpp

In the piece of code below I have written a function with the side effect of changing the first entry of a vector to zero. I then generate a vector called "original", and make a copy called "copy". If I call the function with the side effect using "copy" as argument, "original" is also changed!

I believe that this is caused by R's memory management, "original" is not really copied before I make changes to "copy". And R does not know that the function sideEffect will alter the input, so it does not make a real copy. Can anybody confirm this understanding?

Secondly, is there an elegant way I can force R to make a real copy? By inelegant I mean something like changing and entry in "copy" back and forth.

Thirdly, thinking about it I can not think of a single R function having side effects, is it a programming paradigm in R and if so any reason I should adhere to it?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void sideEffect(NumericVector x) {
   x(0) = 0;
}

/*** R
original <- 5
copy <- original
sideEffect(copy)
print(original) #prints 0
*/
```

Comment: Known, documented and frequently discussed -- look for the `clone()` method, eg by looking at some [**of these previous SO posts**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brcpp%5D+clone).

Comment: There are many R functions with side effects. Most often it's a plot. But functional languages try to avoid unnecessary side effects.